# Get only first N rows met the condition but keep rows where the condition isn't met

Tags: sql, postgresql

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | body |
| 2 | body1 |
| 3 | body |
| 4 | body1 |
| 5 | body1 |
| 6 | body1 |
| 7 | body |
| 8 | body1 |
| 9 | body1 |
| 10 | body |

Is it possible to select first 3 rows where `type` is `body` but keep other rows where `type` isn't equal `body`? Expected result is rows with id from 1 to 7.

Comment: Why are row 8 and 9 excluded? "_keep other rows where type isn't equal body_"

Comment: I would do as `UNION` of 2 `SELECT`s: 3 rows for 'body' and others for not 'body'

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want everything up to the third `body`.   One method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id <= (select t2.id
               from t t2
               where t2.type = 'body'
               order by t2.id
               limit 1 offset 2
              );
```

Note:  This particular formulation assumes that there are at least three `'body'` rows.  It can be tweaked but this is consistent with your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE type = 'body' ORDER BY id LIMIT 3
```

ORDER BY will make sure you select the top rows ordered by the id column

LIMIT 3 will pick only the first 3 results

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is use ranking

reproducing your table with

```
create table test_body (id integer, str_type varchar);
insert into test_body values(1, 'body');
insert into test_body values(2, 'body1');
insert into test_body values(3, 'body');
insert into test_body values(4, 'body1');
insert into test_body values(5, 'body1');
insert into test_body values(6, 'body1');
insert into test_body values(7, 'body');
insert into test_body values(8, 'body1');
insert into test_body values(9, 'body1');
insert into test_body values(10, 'body');
```

The following query calculates the ranking for the condition and then uses it to filter the data

```
with ranking_sel as(
select *, 
case when str_type = 'body' then 1 else 0 end condition,
rank() over (partition by case when str_type = 'body' then 1 else 0 end order by id) rnk from test_body 
)

select * from ranking_sel where rnk <= 3 or condition = 0 order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use window function `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.type ORDER BY t1.id) rnk,
        t1.*
    FROM table t1
) t2
WHERE
 (t2.type = 'body' and rnk <= 3) or (t2.type != 'body')
```